# How to make zsh `run-help` to ignore `sudo` and get help about the following command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zsh

Is it possible to customize zsh so that when I type, say, `sudo ls` and then hit Alt-h to see man page of the command `ls`. The default behavior of `run-help` is to show me the man page of the command `sudo`, instead of `ls`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Run the following lines or add them to your .zshrc.

```
autoload -U run-help
autoload run-help-sudo
```

from [zsh wiki](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/run-help):

> [`run-help`] can be further customized by defining helper functions of
>   the form run-help-*command*.

There are other helper functions, as of version 5.0.8:

- `run-help-git`
- `run-help-ip`
- `run-help-openssl`
- `run-help-p4`
- `run-help-sudo`
- `run-help-svk`
- `run-help-svn`

If you are running a Debian, you can find all helper functions function by:

`dpkg -L zsh-common | grep run-help`